# NameError in UsersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I am currently working on the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. I am trying to add a page for each user in my database by creating an HTML with embedded ruby page in the views directory. The code for show.html.erb is below:

```
    <%= @user.name %>, <%= @user.email %>
```

When I add the user to the user_controller.rb file, it looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end
  end
```

When I run the rails server and click on open up the users/1 URL, I get a NameError complaining about an uninitialized constant. The error and trace is below:

```
NameError in UsersController#show
uninitialized constant UsersController::User

Rails.root: /usr/sample_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:3:in `show'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.12) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.12) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in         
.
.
.
.
```

Please let me know how to go about this because I cannot pass my spec tests with this error.  If anyone has any suggestions or insight I would greatly appreciate them.Thank you.

Comment: Well, do you have `class User` defined in `app/models/user.rb`?

Comment: NO I do not. Actually, I cannot find my user.rb file in the models directory. This is weird because I know I had one before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller file name should be `users_controller.rb`

As you mentioned in comment `you don't have any User model defined`. To create model run `rails g model user name:string email:string`. This will create `User` model with attributes `name and email`.

Try Rails `scaffolding` and see what files it creates(in `controller, model and views` ignore other files for now) and see the contents of those files. To use scaffold for creating `User` is as below:

```
     rails g scaffold user name:string email:string
     rake db:migrate
```